# Express routes alongside socket.io ones

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to handle regular http requests alongside socket.io.

The app.ts file has some REST Route handles, and error handler for all routes that don't exist.

```
app.use("/users", userRouter);
app.use("/products", productRouter);

app.all("*", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  throw new NotFoundError("route");
});
```

Suppose I want to add one route (namespace) that will handle the socket.io connections.

With my current implementation I keep getting an error that the route doesn't exist (from the app.all) because express thinks it's a regular http client.

What is the right way to implement regular http requests alongside socket.io ones?

I know that in order to implement namespace I need to use

```
const io = new Server(httpServer, { cors: { origin: "*" } });
io.of("/socket").on("connection", () => {
  // Do something
});
```

But localhost::PORT/socket is treated as if it is a regular request